# To get all selected elements in the MS Word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am developing a MS Word application. How can I get all selected elements in the document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get selected text from Word Document in C# based Word Add-In?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023296/how-to-get-selected-text-from-word-document-in-c-sharp-based-word-add-in)

Answer (score 2):

The Application/Window class from the Word object model provides the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838682(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns the Selection object that represents a selected range or the insertion point. The [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821048(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Selection class returns the selection type which can help to identify the selected object:

- wdNoSelection - No selection.
- wdSelectionBlock - A block selection.
- wdSelectionColumn - A column selection.
- wdSelectionFrame - A frame selection.
- wdSelectionInlineShape - An inline shape selection.
- wdSelectionIP - An inline paragraph selection.
- wdSelectionNormal - A normal or user-defined selection.
- wdSelectionRow - A row selection.
- wdSelectionShape - A shape selection.